# Search youtube for a video when a link is clicked using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, youtube

Im trying too make a page that will load a youtube video without re-loading the page, when a link is clicked. I had the code working for when a button was pressed and it looked like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".button").click(function() {
        var search = $(".input").val();
        var keyword= encodeURIComponent(search);
        var yt_url='http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q='+keyword+'&format=5&max-results=1&v=2&alt=jsonc';

$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: yt_url,
        dataType:"jsonp",
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.data.items) {
                $.each(response.data.items, function(i,data) {
                    var video_id=data.id;
                    var video_frame="<iframe width='420' height='236' src='http://www.youtube.com/embed/"+video_id+"' frameborder='0' type='text/html'></iframe>";
                    $("#video").html(video_frame); 
                });
            } else {
                $("#video").html("<div id='no'>No Video</div>");
            }
        }
    });
});
});
```

I have been trying to change this code from a tutorial I followed online, to work for a link. I am not sure what I should do next though, I tried changing the classes but came across a problem when getting the search data from a link. what I would like this to improve is:

```
<div id="main_section">
    <div id=ytVid>
        <iframe width="480" height="360" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xJ3-NnNx6Zs" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <p id="1">Jackie Wilson - Reet Petite</p>
    <p id="2">Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody</p>
</div>
```

When someone clicks the "Jackie Wilson - Reet Petite" text or link, It will update the youtube video, as will the Queen song.

Thanks

Edit:
I changed the JavaScript file to this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#songInfo").click(function() {
    function openLink(evt) {
            var search = evt.target.innerHTML;
            var keyword= encodeURIComponent(search);
            ... rest of code ...
```

and the HTML to:

```
<p id="1" onclick="openLink(evt);"> Jackie Wilson - Reet Petite</p>
<p id="2" onclick="openLink(evt);"> Queen - Bohemian Rhapsody</p>
```

When I clicked on the text nothing happened
Sorry, Im quite new to JavaScript in HTML, I should have said earlier.

Answer (score 0):

I think you would have luck doing the same thing with the "onclick" event of the `<p>` tags - [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) says it's valid for those tags.  Something like this:

```
document.getElementById("1").onclick = "openLink(evt);";
```

Then if you need the text of the `<p>` tag, try something like this:

```
function openLink(evt) {
    var search = evt.target.innerHTML;
    var keyword= encodeURIComponent(search);
    ... // just like your unnamed function
}
```

Comment: I tried you code, But i cant get it to work, I have put an example of what i did above.

Comment: I'm not familiar with your `$("#video")` syntax.  Is that equivalent to calling `getElementById()` ?  Sorry I have done quite a bit of javascript but I'm far from an expert.